# Looping Datagridview Controls Using Array Wtih Event Handlers

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am creating a Sub Routine that would create datagridviews depending on my desired number of loops. I am assuming that the problem is that the columns that are to be created for each datagridview are all consolidated in the first created datagridview. The reason why I'm assuming this is because I'm seeing the other datagridviews without columns and rows (just the gray background). My assumption is that my column variable declarations are not appropriate for what I want to do. Please see my code.

Sub routine for creating Datagridview code:

```
 Private Sub DrawGridViewWLoop()
    Dim dgvIterator As Short
    ReDim dgvControlArr(10)

    For dvgIterator = 0 To 3
        dgvControlArr(dvgIterator) = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
        With dgvControlArr(dgvIterator)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(0, 0)
            .AutoSize = True
            .EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .BackgroundColor = Color.White
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
            .AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
            .AllowUserToResizeRows = False
            .ReadOnly = True
            .MultiSelect = False
        End With

        Dim colID_2 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With colID_2
            .HeaderText = "ID"
            .Name = "colID"
            .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
            .HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Width = 300
        End With

        Dim colG_2 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonColumn
        With colG_2
            .HeaderText = "G"
            .Name = "colG"
            .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
            .HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Width = 40
        End With

        Dim colI_2 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With colI_2
            .HeaderText = "I"
            .Name = "colI"
            .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
            .HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        End With

        Dim colO_2 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With colO_2
            .HeaderText = "O"
            .Name = "colO"
            .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
            .HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        End With

        Dim colQ_2 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With colQ_2
            .HeaderText = "Q"
            .Name = "colQ"
            .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
            .HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        End With

        Dim colIn_2 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With colIn_2
            .HeaderText = "In"
            .Name = "colIn"
            .HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
            .HeaderCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            .HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        End With

        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Columns.AddRange(colID_2, colG_2, colI_2, colO_2, colQ_2, colIn_2)

        With dgvControlArr(dgvIterator)
            .Columns("colID").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns("colG").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns("colI").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns("colO").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns("colQ").HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            .Columns("colID").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns("colG").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns("colI").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns("colO").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            .Columns("colQ").SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        End With

        With dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows
            .Add("01")
            .Add("02")
            .Add("03")
            .Add("04")
            .Add("05")
        End With

        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows(1).Cells(2).Value = "Y"
        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows(0).Cells(5).Value = "sample 1"
        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows(2).Cells(5).Value = "sample 3"
        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows(3).Cells(5).Value = "sample 4"
        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows(3).Cells(2).Value = "Y"
        dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = "Y"

        AddHandler dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).SelectionChanged, AddressOf Me.DataGridViews_SelectionChanged
        AddHandler dgvControlArr(dgvIterator).CellContentClick, AddressOf Me.DataGridViews_CellContentClick
    Next
    Me.Controls.AddRange(dgvControlArr)
    GridViewStackOrder()
End Sub
```

Code For Ordering my datagridview locations

```
Private Sub GridViewStackOrder()

    dgvControlArr(0).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 250)
    dgvControlArr(1).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 750)
    dgvControlArr(2).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 1250)
    dgvControlArr(3).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 1750)

End Sub
```

Code For My Event Handlers

```
Private Sub DataGridViews_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView, e As EventArgs)
    sender.ClearSelection()
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridViews_CellContentClick(sender As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse Not e.ColumnIndex = sender.Columns(1).Index Then Return
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        If sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = "Y" Then
            Dim chosenID As String = sender.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value
            MsgBox(chosenID)
        Else
            MsgBox("Input not available.")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My objective here is to create columns and rows for all the gridview not just the first one. Also I would like to prohibit selection for all the datagridviews that's why I created the selection_changed handler. I know that this is pretty basic but please, your ideas will be very helpful. Thanks geniuses!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. You're declaring the counter as following:

```
Dim dgvIterator As Short
```

Now here is your problem, you're mixing d**gv** and d**vg**.

```
For dvgIterator = 0 To 3
    dgvControlArr(dvgIterator) = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
```

To fix this, just replace the above lines with the following lines:

```
For dgvIterator = 0 To 3
    dgvControlArr(dgvIterator) = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
```